# Why ScrollBar's ValueChanged EventTrigger is binding animation to previous value

Tags: wpf, xaml, storyboard, scrollbar, eventtrigger

I have a strange behavior in my WPF application.

I am trying to launch an thickness animation on `ScrollBar.ValueChanged` event for animating an element margin, but every time the scroll bar value changed, the animation is binded to the OLD value of the scroll bar.

Resulting in a gap between the scroll bar value and the margin element.

```
<UserControl.Resources>

        <Storyboard x:Key="AnimationScrollTest">
            <ThicknessAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ElementTest" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin" Duration="0:0:0:0.3" 
                                To="{Binding ElementName=ScrollBarTest, Path=Value, Converter={StaticResource MyVerticalScrollBarValueToMarginConverter}}" />
        </Storyboard>
<UserControl.Resources>

<Grid>
   <ScrollBar x:Name="ScrollBarTest" Grid.RowSpan="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Orientation="Vertical" Right" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" SmallChange="10" LargeChange="100" Value="0" Maximum="2000" >
            <ScrollBar.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="ScrollBar.ValueChanged" >
                    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource AnimationScrollTest}" />
                </EventTrigger>
            </ScrollBar.Triggers>
        </ScrollBar>

        <Border x:Name="ElementTest" Grid.RowSpan="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="50" Height="50" Background="Red"></Border>
</Grid>




public class VerticalScrollBarValueToMarginConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return new Thickness(0, (Double)value, 0, 0);
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

- When the EventTrigger is linked to ScrollBar.Scroll event, it works well.
- When a breakpoint is added in the converter, the value object in the Convert method have the correct value
- If the ElementTest margin is directly binded to the ScrollBar value (without animation), it works well too.

Any idea??

Thanks a lot

PS: sorry for the bad english, I'm french!

Comment: you have a max value of 2000 in scroll bar is that the expected top margin of your Border element too? I got your issue, the issue is due to freezable behavior. lets see how we can solve the same

Comment: The max value of 2000 is just for the example. In the main application, this value is dynamically calculated one time, on LayoutUpdated event.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I attempted to solve the previous value problem with attached properties

xaml

```xml
<Grid xmlns:l="clr-namespace:CSharpWPF">
    <ScrollBar x:Name="ScrollBarTest"
               Grid.RowSpan="3"
               Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
               Orientation="Vertical"
               HorizontalAlignment="Right"
               VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
               SmallChange="10"
               LargeChange="100"
               Value="0"
               Maximum="2000">
    </ScrollBar>
    <Border x:Name="ElementTest"
            Grid.RowSpan="3"
            Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            VerticalAlignment="Top"
            Width="50"
            Height="50"
            Background="Red"
            l:ScrollBarToMarginAnimator.ScrollBar="{Binding ElementName=ScrollBarTest}"></Border>
</Grid>
```

I have removed the storyboard from here and added an attached property `l:ScrollBarToMarginAnimator.ScrollBar` to the target element and binded to the scrollbar `ScrollBarTest`

class for the attached property

```cs
namespace CSharpWPF
{
    public class ScrollBarToMarginAnimator : DependencyObject
    {

        public static ScrollBar GetScrollBar(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            return (ScrollBar)obj.GetValue(ScrollBarProperty);
        }

        public static void SetScrollBar(DependencyObject obj, ScrollBar value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(ScrollBarProperty, value);
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for ScrollBar.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ScrollBarProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("ScrollBar", typeof(ScrollBar), typeof(ScrollBarToMarginAnimator), new PropertyMetadata(null, OnScrollBarChanged));

        private static void OnScrollBarChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {

            ScrollBar sb = e.NewValue as ScrollBar;
            if (sb != null)
                sb.Scroll += (ss, ee) =>
                    {
                        ThicknessAnimation ta = new ThicknessAnimation(new Thickness(0, sb.Value, 0, 0), TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(300));
                        (d as FrameworkElement).BeginAnimation(FrameworkElement.MarginProperty, ta);
                    };
        }

    }
}
```

in this class I am listening to the `Scroll` event of the binded scrollbar and initiating a `ThicknessAnimation` on the attached element's `Margin` property.

above solution will listen any change in scroll bar and will react accordingly by animating margin of the border.

**Multi Scrollbar**

xaml

```xml
<Grid xmlns:l="clr-namespace:CSharpWPF">
    <ScrollBar x:Name="vertical"
           Grid.RowSpan="3"
           Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
           Orientation="Vertical"
           HorizontalAlignment="Right"
           VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
           SmallChange="10"
           LargeChange="100"
           Value="0"
           Maximum="2000"/>
    <ScrollBar x:Name="horizontal"
           Grid.RowSpan="3"
           Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
           Orientation="Horizontal"
           HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
           VerticalAlignment="Top"
           SmallChange="10"
           LargeChange="100"
           Value="0"
           Maximum="2000"/>
    <Border x:Name="ElementTest"
        Grid.RowSpan="3"
        Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        VerticalAlignment="Top"
        Width="50"
        Height="50"
        Background="Red"
        l:ScrollBarToMarginAnimator.Vertical="{Binding ElementName=vertical}"
        l:ScrollBarToMarginAnimator.Horizontal="{Binding ElementName=horizontal}"/>
</Grid>
```

I have added another scrollbar and attached two properties to the border.

cs

```cs
namespace CSharpWPF
{

    public class ScrollBarToMarginAnimator : DependencyObject
    {

        public static ScrollBar GetVertical(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            return (ScrollBar)obj.GetValue(VerticalProperty);
        }

        public static void SetVertical(DependencyObject obj, ScrollBar value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(VerticalProperty, value);
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Vertical.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty VerticalProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Vertical", typeof(ScrollBar), typeof(ScrollBarToMarginAnimator),
            new PropertyMetadata(null, (d, e) => AttachAnimation(d, e, true)));

        public static ScrollBar GetHorizontal(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            return (ScrollBar)obj.GetValue(HorizontalProperty);
        }

        public static void SetHorizontal(DependencyObject obj, ScrollBar value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(HorizontalProperty, value);
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Horizontal.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty HorizontalProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Horizontal", typeof(ScrollBar), typeof(ScrollBarToMarginAnimator),
            new PropertyMetadata(null, (d, e) => AttachAnimation(d, e, false)));


        private static void AttachAnimation(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e, bool isVertical)
        {
            ScrollBar sb = e.NewValue as ScrollBar;
            if (sb != null)
                sb.Scroll += (ss, ee) =>
                {
                    FrameworkElement fw = d as FrameworkElement;
                    Thickness newMargin = fw.Margin;
                    if (isVertical)
                        newMargin.Top = sb.Value;
                    else
                        newMargin.Left = sb.Value;

                    ThicknessAnimation ta = new ThicknessAnimation(newMargin, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(300));
                    fw.BeginAnimation(FrameworkElement.MarginProperty, ta);
                };
        }

    }
}
```

I have created two properties and attached the animation using a flag

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Listening the ValueChanged event, this is a nice workaround.
However, in the main application, I have two ScrollBars (horizontal and vertical), animating the margin.
Before that, in XAML, I used a MultiValueConverter on the ThicknessAnimations to bind the scroll bar value AND the current object margin, to create a new Margin with both.

But now, I don't know how to manage two scroll bars, animating the margin of one element, with one dependency object. 
Any help?

Comment: I'll help you attach the other one too, let me find a PC. Meanwhile you can try creating another property and attach it to the border and set the value to another scrollbar and attach the event to animate it to. Give it a try meanwhile I attempt to do that.

Comment: Yeah, but on the ValueChanged event on the first ScrollBar, I can't get the value of the second ScrollBar to generate a correct Thickness. Attach two properties to the border seems to create two dependency object, each one with one scroll bar and not the other.
Maybe I've done something wrong... :-)
I've tried to change the property to an object[] one, and set this property with a multibinding containing the two scrollbars. It does not work, the object[0] and object[1] are fully setted in the converter, and both null in the DependencyObject.

Comment: Great answer, thanks a lot pushpraj!
I just add a RoutedEvent to the DependencyObject to manage the end of the animation.

Comment: You too did a great job! happy coding :)